# 多変数関数の積分をTexで入力するには？

Tags: latex

Latexで、以下のような四重積分を記載するにはどのように入力すればよいのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

積分記号のところだけですが，次でよいと思います．

```
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
```